# Simulate Search and Select an option react-select

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, integration-testing, enzyme, react-select

I am trying simulate search and select an option from the react-select component version 3.1.1. But it always returning the first item in the list.

Below is my component which is working fine in UI but not for integration testing.

```
<Select
       id="test-dropdown"
       inputId="testsInput"
       className="select-label-input-margin"
       classNamePrefix="select"
       name="test-dropdown"
       placeholder='test placeholder'
       isSearchable={true}
       isClearable={true}
       options={testsOptions}
       value={selectedValue}
       onChange={option => console.log(option)}
       noOptionsMessage={() => 'No result found'}
     />
```

To simulate that I am using these piece of code
Here wrapper is the class component that I am mounting.

```
wrapper.find('Select#test-dropdown').find('input[id="testsInput"]').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Test 1 title' } }),
// wrapper.find('input[id="testsInput"]').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Test 1 title' } }),    
//If I use this it will select second value in the array
wrapper.find('input[id="testsInput"]').simulate('keyDown', arrowDown),
// wrapper.find('input[id="test-dropdown"]').simulate('keyDown', arrowDown),
// wrapper.find('input[id="test-dropdown"]').simulate('keyDown', arrowDown),
wrapper.find('input[id="testsInput"]').simulate('keyDown', tabButton)
```

I also looked into this issue from the [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1357) but no help.

Any idea how we can simulate search and select the option?